# Load data from SQL Server on ASP.NET page load, then use javascript/jquery to do select from loaded data

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, asp.net

My goal is to make a cascading dropdown for country then state, where the data is on an SQL Server and not have to deal with the data persistence of postbacks/callbacks.

I can use an SQLDataSource to pull all the needed information on page load, but how do I run a query against that data source?

Edit:

I was able to fix my immeadiate issue using DevExpress tools, mainly the ASPxCallbackPanel. I am new to web design and I think my understanding of callbacks/postbacks was way off. From what I have read, a postback refreshes the entire page which will reset variables/fields. A callback only transfers information and the page maintains it state.

I still want to find a way to do this without the DevExpress. So how would I either have javascript read from an SQLDataSource, or have another method of loading from SQL by the server to something else that javascript can understand?

Comment: Suggestion: Based on the title of your post - _try_ to make/convert/serialize/load the result set into something that client script can use (array/object/json) and go from there.

Comment: @EdSF I really don't even know where to start, would you be able to post an answer explaining what you mean with some sample code?